# MapBox map.setView(locale.getLatLng() not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mapbox

I'm implementing MapBox into my site. I've modeled this after:

```
https://www.mapbox.com/guides/building-a-store-locator/
```

I have everything set up to currently pull in the locations I've entered into my locations/new form. Then I'm displaying the list of locations next to the map, but when I click on a location name the map isn't moving to the location. Only the popup box comes up with the marker (which is correct).

Now when I zoom all the way out to the edge of the map, I finally see the marker is planted at the very bottom edge of the map, not on any latitude/longitude.

So I've been able to identify that this isn't pulling in the lat/long from my database for any of my entered locations, but I can't see where I need to fix this. Can someone help?

LOCATION.RB:

```
def to_geo_json_feature
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": 
    {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            latitude,
            longitude
        ]
    },
    "properties": 
    {
        "name": name,
        "address": address1 + ', ' + address2,
        "city": city,
        "country": "United States",
        "zip": zip,
        "state": state
    }
}
end
```

LOCATIONS.HTML.RB

```
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = '<my access token is here>';
    var geojson = [  
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": <%= raw Location.all.map(&:to_geo_json_feature).to_json %>
    }];

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '<my mapbox map id is here>')
.setView([38.909671288923, -77.034084142948], 12);

var listings = document.getElementById('listings');
var locations = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

locations.setGeoJSON(geojson);

function setActive(el) 
{
    var siblings = listings.getElementsByTagName('div');

    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) 
    {
        siblings[i].className = siblings[i].className
        .replace(/active/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    }

    el.className += ' active';
}

locations.eachLayer(function(locale) 
{
    // Shorten locale.feature.properties to just `prop` so we're not
    // writing this long form over and over again.
    var prop = locale.feature.properties;

    // Each marker on the map.
    var popup = '<h3>' + prop.name + '</h3><div>' + prop.address + '<br>' + prop.city + ', ' + prop.state + ' ' + prop.zip;

    link.onclick = function() 
    {
        setActive(listing);

        // When a menu item is clicked, animate the map to center
        // its associated locale and open its popup.
        map.setView(locale.getLatLng(), 16);
        locale.openPopup();
        return false;
    };

    // Marker interaction
    locale.on('click', function() 
    {
        // 1. center the map on the selected marker.
        map.panTo(locale.getLatLng());

        // 2. Set active the markers associated listing.
        setActive(listing);
    });

    popup += '</div>';
    locale.bindPopup(popup);
});
</script>
```